# What's the Django way of doing an "order by" dropdown filter?

Tags: django

I need a basic search query 'order by' dropdown to use with a RawQuerySet. I did some searching and couldn't find a specific example although the existence of Forms and Widgets which i don't fully understand makes me think I’m reinventing the wheel.

## view

```
def search(request, limit=1000):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    mapping = OrderedDict([
            ('time_desc', 'time_modified DESC'),
            ('time_asc', 'time_modified ASC'),
            ('relevance', None)])
    sort = request.GET.get('sort')
    _ = mapping.get(sort)
    order_by = 'ORDER BY %s' % _ if _ else ''

    dropdown = {'choices': mapping.keys(),
                'selected_choice': sort if sort else 'relevance'}
    query = sanitize_query(query)
    results = SphinxTable.objects.db_manager('sphinx').raw("SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH('%(query)s') %(order_by)s LIMIT %(limit)s" % locals())

    return render(request,
                  'search.html',
                  {'results': results,
                   'dropdown': dropdown})
```

## template

```
<ul id="filter">
    <li>
        <h3>{{ dropdown.selected_choice }}▾</h3>
        <ul>
            {% for choice in dropdown.choices %}
                {% if choice == dropdown.selected_choice %}
                    <li># {{ choice|capfirst }}</li>
                {% else %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ request.path }}?q={{ request.GET.q }}&sort={{ choice }}">
                        {{ choice|capfirst }}
                        </a>
                    </li>

                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is a `SphinxTable`? The first google hit for "SphinxTable Django" is this question.

Comment: Yes, You are reinventing the wheel in such a dangerous way! (SQL Injection [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection])

Comment: Yep, query is injectable here, could you use [RawSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.expressions.RawSQL) instead of raw here ? It'll take your params as argument, instead of having you generating the SQL query string manualy.

Comment: SphinxTable is a model for a Sphinx search index, it's a covering index that mirrors a Postgres table. I have a function to format/sanitize the query that's not a concern.  I am mainly interested in whether I should be using a form/widget.